# How to represent a composite key in a psql schema?

Tags: postgresql, schema

I have a postgresql schema, `genre`, that looks like: `genre(genre: string, ISBN: integer)`, where `genre` and `ISBN` are meant to be a composite key. However, I do not know how to represent this in the schema itself.

Do I simply underline both of them like I would a normal primary key? Or am I supposed to write it another way?

Comment: 1) To be less confusing I would rewrite this as *I have a postgresql table, genre ...*. `Schema` can have two meanings and here you are referring to the meaning as a table definition.  2) `Create table genre(genre varchar, ISBN integer, PRIMARY KEY(genre, ISBN));` per  here [Create Table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) *Examples* section.